# The equation of a family of circles passing through two given points

Tags: circles

We have to write the equation of a family of circles passing through two given points $(x_1,y_1)$ & $(x_2, y_2)$

From these points , I only know one circle that is

$$(x_1-x)(x_2-x)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)=0$$

But now how Can I write other equations .

Comment: make the ansatz $$(x-x_M)^2+(y-y_M)^2=R^2$$

Comment: the middelpoints of these circles are situated on the perpendicular bisector

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120609/find-the-equation-of-the-circle-which-passes-through-the-origin-and-cuts-off/2120614#2120614

Comment: Why does $S + \lambda L =0$ work? That is how we parametrise a typical circle passing through two points using the equation of the circle passing through them and the line passing through them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Family of circle passing through two given points $A(x_1, y_1)$ and $B(x_2, y_2)$.

[image: page 1]

[For more details see this.](http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-coordinate-geometry/family-of-circles.aspx)

Comment: Why we can do it like this, that is S+$\lambda$L=0

Comment: You have to see 5th part. That is your answer.

Comment: @Koolman what will you substitute in place of S ?

Answer (score 4):

We know that $(x-x_1)(x-x_2) + (y-y_1)(y-y_2) $ is the equation of the circle having the two points as it's diameter and that $\lambda \begin {vmatrix} x & y & 1\\ x_1 & y_1 & 1\\ x_2 & y_2 & 1\end {vmatrix} $ is the equation of a line passing through the two points. Thus, the required family of circles is $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2) + (y-y_1)(y-y_2) +\lambda \begin {vmatrix} x & y & 1\\ x_1 & y_1 & 1\\ x_2 & y_2 & 1\end {vmatrix} =0 $$

Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965414/how-to-determine-family-of-circles-passing-through-two-given-points). Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any difference in your answer and the answer in the link I provided?

Comment: Its totally copy paste.

Comment: @Kanwaljit Singh Sir, I regret to say that you have provided a link which states the same thing that I had memorised for preparation. I am sorry that I didn't load your answer while writing mine.

Comment: Why we can do it like this, that is S+λL=0

Answer (score 2):

Here is an understanding of what it means to change $\lambda$ in the equation:
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2) + (y-y_1)(y-y_2) +\lambda \begin {vmatrix} x & y & 1\\ x_1 & y_1 & 1\\ x_2 & y_2 & 1\end {vmatrix} =0 $$

Fixing the point as $(x_1,y_1)=0$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(2,1)$, find my graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). Here is a gif of the above:

[image]

Explanation: When $\lambda=0$, at that point the circle is the one having diameter as the line segment from $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. As we vary $\lambda$ we get a family of circles still passing through these two points on the line (and no other one the line passing through them) but this time this line segment is chord of the circle.